# choroplethr sudden error in choro$render

Tags: r, choroplethr

very new to R, and this is my first question so please be kind :)

I was working with the choroplethr/choroplethrMaps/choroplethrZip packages for a few days without any issues, but suddenly, I keep getting the an error when I try to visualize a map--I have pasted the output below, and any help would be deeply appreciated. 
The most perplexing issue for me is why it suddenly stopped working--I didn't add anything to the script--I get the same error with  choroplethr/choroplethrMaps as well. Many thanks for your expertise and patience!

```
data(df_pop_zip)

choro = ZipChoropleth$new(df_pop_zip)

choro$title = "2012 ZCTA Population Estimates"

choro$ggplot_scale = scale_fill_brewer(name="Population", palette=2, drop=FALSE)

choro$set_zoom_zip(state_zoom="florida", county_zoom=NULL, msa_zoom=NULL, zip_zoom=NULL)

choro$render()
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : attempt to apply non-function

Comment: Hi. I'm the package author and looking into this. From what I can tell this is an issue with how the main choroplethr package is being built under R 3.2.4. See https://github.com/arilamstein/choroplethr/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your error can be solved by typing the following:

```
# install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("choroplethr", "arilamstein")
library(choroplethr)
```

If I install choroplethr from CRAN I can replicate your error. If I install it from github I can solve it. Note that the actual R code is currently the same in both github and CRAN, because I recently submitted a new version to CRAN.

When I load the version of choroplethr from CRAN I get this warning:

```
> library(choroplethr)
Warning message:
package ‘choroplethr’ was built under R version 3.2.4
```

However, the current version of R is 3.2.3. So it looks like CRAN is using different version of R for what they are distrbuting to the public and what they are using to build packages. I'm not sure why this is.

Note that while I think this solution will work for you, I don't find it particularly satisfying or elegant. I could probably install the development version of R to see if I can replicate (and debug) the issue myself. But at this point I'd rather wait until they officially release the new version to see if it is still present. I really don't have much experience with the development versions of R.

Comment: b/c _"R version 3.2.4 (Very Secure Dishes) prerelease versions will appear starting Monday 2016-02-29. Final release is scheduled for Thursday 2016-03-10"_

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Very relieved to have it "work" again--and thanks for doing what you do so well, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Note, this is fixed with choroplethr v3.5.1, which is now on CRAN.